# How can I display my Firebase notification message in my textviews in background mode?

Tags: firebase-notifications

I want to display my Firebase notification message in textviews in background mode, but it's only working and displaying in foreground mode.

I have already used `broadcastReceiver`. It is working, but only in the foreground. How can I make it work in background mode?

This is my Firebase Messaging Service class:

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView notificationTitle, notificationMessage;


    public static final String NODE_USERS = "users";
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mHandler,new IntentFilter("com.example.linguanotification_FCM-MESSAGE"));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        notificationTitle=findViewById(R.id.title_notification);
        notificationMessage=findViewById(R.id.notification_message);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("updates");

        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            String token = task.getResult().getToken();
                            saveToken(token);
                        } else {

                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    private void saveToken(String token) {
        String email = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
        User user = new User(email, token);

        DatabaseReference dbUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(NODE_USERS);

        dbUsers.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Token Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mHandler = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
            String message=intent.getStringExtra("message");

            notificationTitle.setText(title);
            notificationMessage.setText(message);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mHandler);
    }
}


public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

            NotificationHelper.displayNotification(getApplicationContext(), title, body);
        }

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size()>0)
        {
            String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
            String message= remoteMessage.getData().get("message");

            Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.linguanotification_FCM-MESSAGE");
            intent.putExtra("title",title);
            intent.putExtra("message",message);
            LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager=LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
            localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);

        }


    }
}


public class NotificationHelper {

    public static void displayNotification(Context context, String title, String body) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ProfileActivity.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context,
                100,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
        );

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.dd)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText(body)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);

        NotificationManagerCompat mNotificationMgr = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        mNotificationMgr.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

    }

}


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //1. Notification Channel
    //2. Notification Builder
    //3. Notification Manager

    public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "12";
    public static final String CHANNEL_NAME = "23";
    public static final String CHANNEL_DESC = "34";

    private EditText editTextEmail, editTextPassword;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            channel.setDescription(CHANNEL_DESC);
            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        editTextEmail = findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPassword = findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

        findViewById(R.id.buttonSignUp).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                createUser();
            }
        });



    }

    private void createUser() {
        final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();

        if (email.isEmpty()) {
            editTextEmail.setError("Email required");
            editTextEmail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (password.isEmpty()) {
            editTextPassword.setError("Password required");
            editTextPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (password.length() < 6) {
            editTextPassword.setError("Password should be atleast 6 char long");
            editTextPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            startProfileActivity();
                        }else{
                            if(task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException){
                                userLogin(email, password);
                            }else{
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                });
    }

    private void userLogin(String email, String password){

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            startProfileActivity();
                        }else{
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }


    //here we are checking if the user is not null then the user already logged in
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null)
        {
            startProfileActivity();

        }
    }

    private void startProfileActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```